# Object required run time error 424 in vba if statement

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So, I'm trying to run this login system in Powerpoint. Everything is going fine until I run into this particular piece of code:

```
Private Sub Login_Click()
If Password.Text = PasswordReg.Text Then
SlideShowWindows(Index:=1).View.GotoSlide 6
Else
MsgBox "Incorrect Password", 16, "Incorrect Password"
End if
Password.Text = ""
End Sub
```

My goal is to have the user enter a password first before they can proceed to the next slide, but before that can happen they need to "register", aka give their own password which will be typed in a text box named "PasswordReg", which is located in a different slide.

If `PasswordReg.Text` was replaced with `"insertpasswordhere"` then it runs fine, but I wanted the password to be variable rather than the coder having been the one to set it. Is that not allowed in if-then-else statements or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: At a guess, `Password.Reg` is not visible from here. Maybe you need to prepend it with the slide object that it's on.

Comment: Solved! I forgot to prepend it to its slide as you said. Thank you!